# Pairwise comparison inside array in Julia

Tags: arrays, comparison, julia, pairwise

Suppose we have a 6-element array in Julia, for example, `Int64[1,1,2,3,3,4]`. If we want to compare two arrays elementwise, we know we can use ".=="; but my goal is to do all the pairwise comparisons inside the above array: if the elements (i,j) of each pair are equal, I set it to 1 (or true), but if they are different, I set it to 0. All the pairwise comparisons are stored in a 6x6 matrix. Is it possible to do that in Julia without the loop for? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the fact that broadcasting will compare rows to columns to simply do a comparison between the array and its transpose:

```
julia> A = [1,1,2,3,3,4]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 3
 3
 4

julia> A .== A'
6×6 BitArray{2}:
  true   true  false  false  false  false
  true   true  false  false  false  false
 false  false   true  false  false  false
 false  false  false   true   true  false
 false  false  false   true   true  false
 false  false  false  false  false   true
```

Comment: Wow, wonderful!!! I tried A.== A without the quote at the end with no success! The solution was so simple! Thank you!

Comment: On version 0.6 I surprisingly find that `[a==b for a in A, b in B]` is about 4 times faster.

Comment: `[a == b for a in A', b in A]` is about 3 times faster in Julia v0.7 too, though the result is a `1x6x6 Array{Bool, 3}`. Adding a `squeeze` call to get a `6x6 Array{Bool, 2}` brings the time back up to the `.==`'s time.